# How to implement "issue and submit back" pattern in C#?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

In class library I am currently working on, I need to implement a mechanism in which class users will get hold of an item by operating on an Issuer class:

```
class Issuer {
    public Item GetItem () {
        return queue.Pop ();
    }
}

//at some other place
var item = issuer.GetItem ();
//work on item and submit back to Issuer
```

How can I implement this pattern which minimizes the risk that user of the class doesn't even bother to submit it back?

My order of preference would be:

- Class user doesn't have to explicitly submit it back
- Class user has to explicitly submit it back but it is not possible to get away without submitting (exceptions???)
- It is possible to even get away without submitting it back but the design encourage user not to do it

I know it is not a crystal clear question but any suggestions/design-pattern to implement above would be helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this would be using the `IDisposable` interface. This way, users could possibly take advantage of the `using` statement during usage:

```
using (var item = issuer.GetItem())
{
    // Work on item
} // Item is released on Dispose()
```

The issuer could simply listen to an event to get the item back. However, if the item gets passed around, it might not be your best bet. In this case, a simple `Close()` or `Release()` method (again with the issuer listening on an event) might just do the trick.

In most cases, it's best that users explicitly - in some way - release the acquired item.

If some *inconsiderate* user omits to release an item, you could always fall back on the *Finalizer* along with the standard Dispose pattern. However, you must be **very careful** not to *resurrect* the item (keeping a reference once it's finalized).

Comment: Thanks. I like the tip of using Dispose pattern but unfortunately the usage of item is likely to spread across multiple methods. Your suggestion to listen to event might be useful. Should I force the users to implement an interface which has an event I can listen to?

Comment: Declaring an event such as `Closed` or `Released` on Item (invoked when `Close()` or `Release()`) is called by the user will suffice. The user won't be constrained to implement anything. Issuer would listen to those event and *regain control* on the item.

Comment: I really don't know why I insisted on Close and Release; It could have easily been Sumbit!

Answer (score 2):

Maintain a collection of issued Items, perhaps storing when they were issued and the class they were issued to. That way you don't have to explicitly resubmit the item.
Resubmitting removes from the issued collection obviously. You then have the option of throwing exceptions based on 'dirty' data in a number of ways if the issued collection still has items in. 
You could:

- handle events from the requesting class if you stored that for example form closing events
- periodically throw an excpetion for all items older than x
- if the number of outstanding items goes above a certain threshold

One thing I would say is perhaps look into a static issuer rather than have it as an instance method.

Comment: Actually, that's pretty elegant.  If he wants to enforce all items getting returned, then at the process end throw a custom exception if the issued count is greater than zero.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like IDisposable might be useful here. What about:

`class Item { }`

```
class Issuer: IDisposable
{
    Queue<Item> queue = new Queue<Item>();
    List<Item> deliveredItems = new List<Item>();

    public Item GetItem()
    {
        Item item = queue.Dequeue();
        deliveredItems.Add(item);
        return item;
    }

    public void SubmitItem(Item item)
    {
        deliveredItems.Remove(item);

        // do some operation here
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        foreach (Item item in deliveredItems)
        {
            SubmitItem(item);
        }
    }
}
```

As soon as your Issuer is disposed, each of the delivered items that haven't been submitted back will be submitted back automatically.

Comment: Thanks for answer (it is interesting really) but there will be only one instance of Issuer in application. A single source of items. Any more suggestions....

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer considering making it static then if there can only be one Issuer - it prevents issues with accidental occurances of multiple issuers

Answer (score -1):

Use an event to let the Issuer know that an item was gotten and pass it back to the Issuer using an event.

Tony